# gulp live-reload/live-reload chrome plugin doesn't work OS X el capitan version 10.11.6

Tags: javascript, gulp, livereload

I cannot get this seemingly simple plugin to work...this setup works perfectly fine on my co-workers machine

I have the chrome extension, turned on, and I'm working with a gulpfile. The relevant gulp code:

```
// misc dependencies but this one is in... 
...
const livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
...

//default task
gulp.task('default', ['html', 'styles', 'scripts', 'watch']);
gulp.task('build', ['html', 'styles', 'scripts']);

// templating task
gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('views/**/*.html')
    .pipe(livereload());
});

//styles build/minification
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('client/scss/styles.scss', {
        noCache: true,
        style: 'compressed'
    })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/stylesheets'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('client/js/script.js')
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
        .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/javascripts'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

// uses livereload
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('views/**/*.html', ['html']);
  gulp.watch('client/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('client/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload :

> 3.x Upgrade Notice gulp-livereload will not automatically listen for changes. You now have to manually call livereload.listenunless you set
>   the option start: livereload({ start**:** true })

As you can see in my code, `listen` is called manually. I tried doing `.pipe(livereload({start:true}));` but it still won't live reload.

**My machine stats:**
OXS El Capitan
Version 10.11.6
iMac (27-inch, Late 2012)

**My browser stats:**
Google chrome = Version 74.0.3729.6 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)

**Plugin stats:**
Livereload = Version 2.1.0

Any ideas? What do I do?